# Translate Urdu to English using SpeechRecognizer

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I trying to Translate my Urdu speech into English. I am working with SpeechRecognizer since this morning but it is not working for me. Here is my code.

```
mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getContext());
mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-pk");
```

The results are: I speak in Urdu and it converts in Roman Urdu or Urdu. Not in English.

Comment: try as single "en"

Comment: i did this but its showing in Roman Urdu not in English translation

Comment: Did you find solution ?